# Apache Impala schema/ data deployment

Tags: database, deployment, database-schema, impala

Are there any tools (like flywaydb) that allows for schema/ lookup data setup to be deployed as part of code deployment for Apache Impala? Does flywaydb support Impala - I have used it for a number of other DBs but I didn't see any mention of Apache Impala

Thanks